# Does collection's Counter keeps data sorted?

Tags: python

I was reading python collections's [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#counter-objects). It says following:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter({'z': 9,'a':4, 'c':2, 'b':8, 'y':2, 'v':2})
Counter({'z': 9, 'b': 8, 'a': 4, 'c': 2, 'y': 2, 'v': 2})
```

Somehow these printed values are printed in descending order (9 > 8 > 4 > 2). Why is it so? Does `Counter` store values sorted?

PS: Am on python 3.7.7

Comment: What's your version of python?

Comment: *"Changed in version 3.7: As a dict subclass, Counter inherited the capability to remember insertion order. Math operations on Counter objects also preserve order. Results are ordered according to when an element is first encountered in the left operand and then by the order encountered in the right operand."*

Comment: No, no it does not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In terms of the data stored in a `Counter` object: The data is insertion-ordered as of Python 3.7, because `Counter` is a subclass of the built-in `dict`.  Prior to Python 3.7, there was no guaranteed order of the data.

However, the behavior you are seeing is coming from `Counter.__repr__`.  We can see from the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a834e2d8e1230c17193c19b425e83e0bf736179e/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L731) that it will first try to display using the [`Counter.most_common`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) method, which sorts by value in descending order.  If that fails because the values are not sortable, it will fall back to the `dict` representation, which, again, is insertion-ordered.

Comment: I wonder what is used to obtain the representation in the IPython console. The line in the OP prints in insertion order, but `repr(...)` or `str(...)` prints the most common elements first (python 3.7.7 and 3.8.11)

Comment: @PranavHosangadi The output in the OP has the most common elements first.

Comment: @Barmar yeah, I meant [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHdpm.png). I though the REPL used `repr()` to print the value of the expression, so was surprised to see that the order of keys in Out[3] != the order in Out[4]

Comment: @PranavHosangadi - I think that the difference between 3 and 4 is that 4 is `repr(repr(c))`. `repr(c)` returns a string and then ipython reprs it again.

Comment: @tdelaney that wouldn't change the order of the keys though. I updated my comment to clarify

Comment: Now am just guessing if this behavior can lead to any surprises. Can you guess any? It will  if it returns similarly sorted keys in any of its other methods (apart from obviously `most_common`), which does not seem to be the case, right? Also I feel that they really should just keep insertion order as name `__repr__` does not give sense of `most_common`. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The order [depends on the python version](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

For python < 3.7, there is no guaranteed order, since python 3.7 the order is that of insertion.

> Changed in version 3.7: As a dict subclass, Counter inherited the
> capability to remember insertion order. Math operations on Counter
> objects also preserve order. Results are ordered according to when an
> element is first encountered in the left operand and then by the order
> encountered in the right operand.

Example on python 3.8 (3.8.10 [GCC 9.4.0]):

```
from collections import Counter
Counter({'z': 9,'a':4, 'c':2, 'b':8, 'y':2, 'v':2})
```

Output:

```
Counter({'z': 9, 'a': 4, 'c': 2, 'b': 8, 'y': 2, 'v': 2})
```

##### how to check that `Counter` doesn't sort by count

As `__str__` in `Counter` return the `most_common`, it is not a reliable way to check the order.

Convert to `dict`, the `__str__` representation will be faithful.

```
c = Counter({'z': 9,'a':4, 'c':2, 'b':8, 'y':2, 'v':2})

print(dict(c))
# {'z': 9, 'a': 4, 'c': 2, 'b': 8, 'y': 2, 'v': 2}
```

Comment: But when you print it, it doesn't print in insertion order, it prints in decreasing count order.

Comment: @Barmar that's not true on my system. In python 3.9, insertion order is preserved (in ipython)

Comment: I tried it in 3.9 and reproduced the OP's result. `counter.keys()` and `counter.values()` return them in insertion order, but `print(counter)` shows them in decreasing count order.

Comment: `collections.Counter('abcdef' 'abc' 'xyz' 'xz' 'afq')` prints as `Counter({'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 2, 'f': 2, 'x': 2, 'z': 2, 'd': 1, 'e': 1, 'y': 1, 'q': 1})`

Comment: @Barmar sorry was python 3.8 (I was in a VM + jupyter), that said OP didn't use `print`

Comment: btw running the same code in python 3.9 gave exact same output... I used https://www.python.org/shell/